# Partially Merging Data Sets in R

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I have two data files that look like this:

```
bin chrom   chromStart  chromEnd    name    score   strand
23  chr1    119537649   119537708   A_14_P109202    1000    +
109 chr1    37879762    37879821    A_16_P15088121  1000    +
129 chr1    59113425    59113484    A_16_P00074945  1000    +
138 chr1    68288459    68288517    A_16_P00088142  1000    +
```

and

```
Hybridization REF   TCGA-02-0001-01C-01D-0185-02       
Composite Element REF   normalizedLog2Ratio    
A_14_P112718    0.034472223    
A_16_P15000916  -0.038733669       
A_16_P15001074  -0.498562753       
A_16_P00000012  -0.269915751
```

.

Using the names from the first column of the second file, I need to extract additional data from the data table in the first file. However, not every name in the second file appears in the first. I am having problems getting the files to merge properly. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried and what did/did not work? Please share a sample dataset that replicates the problem you are facing.

Answer (score 1):

if you place `all.x=TRUE` in the merge command; all of the records from the first data frame will be in the merged dataframe, even if they don't have a match in the second.  Is that the problem you were encountering?  In the example that you gave none of the rownames matched any of the observations in the name variable.

```
bin<-c(23,109,129,138)
chrom<-c("chr1","chr1","chr1","chr1")
chromStart<-c(119537649,37879762,59113425,68288459)  
name<-c("A_14_P109202", "A_16_P15088121", "A_16_P00074945","A_16_P00088142")
b<- data.frame(cbind(bin,chrom,chromStart,name))

y <- data.frame(c(0.034472223    ,-0.038733669 , -0.498562753 ,-0.269915751)) 
rownames(y)<-c("A_14_P112718","A_16_P15000916","A_16_P15001074","A_16_P00000012")


print(b)
print(y)

#check the rows
nrow(b)
nrow(y)

#write rownames to new variable
y$name <- rownames(y)

#conduct merge
newdataframe <- merge(b, y, by=("name"), all.x = TRUE )

#check number of rows
nrow(newdataframe)
```